# How to fetch data from a specific JSON file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript, fetch

I have one issue with fetching data from a json file.

The json file has some sub arrays and I want to map it. I created a codesandbox page and need help for mapping the related data: https://codesandbox.io/s/json-data-fetch-c00rf

When you open the link you will see that I have used React fetching with useEffect but it is not restricted with that, that means you can use another thing.

The json data coming from here: https://web-coding-challenge.vercel.joyn.de/api/blocks

Here is the code as well:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState<any[]>([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://web-coding-challenge.vercel.joyn.de/api/blocks`)
      .then((results) => results.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setTodos(data);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {todos.map((post: any) => (
        <div>
          <h1>{post.id}</h1>
          <h2>{post.assets.primaryImage.url}</h2>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response constains assets as an nested array. So you can use reduce and get all the elements in one array and then iterate it to create list

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState<any[]>([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://web-coding-challenge.vercel.joyn.de/api/blocks`)
      .then((results) => results.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const responseData = data.reduce((acc:any,curr:any)=>{
          const assets = curr.assets;
             acc.push(...assets)
          return acc ;
          },[])
        setTodos(responseData);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {todos.map((post: any) => (
        <div>
          <h1>{post.id}</h1>
          <h2>{post.primaryImage.url}</h2>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can map through the `post.assets` and return your required jsx

For an example here I'm listing all the urls in a list

```js
    return (
    <div className="App">
      {todos.length && todos.map((post: any) => (
        <div>
          <h2>{post.id}</h2>
          <ul>
          {post.assets.map((asset: any, index: number)=>{
            return (
              <li key={index}>{asset.primaryImage.url}</li>
            )
          })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/json-data-fetch-forked-0gsup?file=/src/App.tsx)